# Display associated value of foreign key in createview of django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models: `store` and `claim` where `store` is the foreign key of `claim`. I am using the `CreateView` generic views. In the form at frontend, I can see the list of `store` as like `username` + `Store` but I want to display the store's name as option's label and id in value in the dropdown list.

The two models are like:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Ext_User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    ....

class Claim(models.Model):    
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expense = models.DecimalField(max_digits=999, decimal_places=0)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Ext_User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....
```

class of creating claim:

```
class ClaimCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Claim
    template_name = 'claim/claim_form.html'
    fields = ['store', 'expense']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.customer = self.request.user   
    return super().form_valid(form)

def test_func(self):
    claim = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == claim.customer:
        return True
    return False
```

what I can see at frontend:

[image]
I want to display the `store name` instead of these default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `__str__()` method of Store model

Whenever we try to print any object in Python, python internally calls it's `__str__()` method to get the string representation of that object.

So we can override the default `__str__()` if we want to provide custom representation of our object.

For your Store model you can even do something like this:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Ext_User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s owned by %s " % (self.store_name, self.user)
```

So whenever you'll try to print any `Store` object, this `__str__()` method will be called for that particular instance and value returned by this method will be printed, which can be something like `ABC Store owned by Xyz`

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#str

Comment: can you explain little bit more  or show some examples or add few more code that would be fine, because I am new at django, however, thanks to answer